# NHibernate Mapping doesn't work

Tags: nhibernate

I created console application, database, model, XML-file and then I wrote this code

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Driver;

namespace NHibernateDemo
{
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
                {
                    x.ConnectionString = "Server=.; Database=NHibernateDemo; Integrated Security = SSPI;";
                    x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                    x.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
                });
            cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var customers = session.CreateCriteria<Customer>()
                                       .List<Customer>();
                foreach (var customer in customers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", customer.FirstName, customer.LastName);
                }
                tx.Commit();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

    }
}
}
```

I didn't get any error and any exception, but I didn't get any information from database too, just string `"Enter any key to exit..."` in console.
What's wrong?

**UPD**
XML-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mappin xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                  assembly="NHibernateDemo"
                  namespace="NHibernateDemo">
    <class name="Customer">
        <id name="Id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="FirstName"/>
        <property name="LastName"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mappin>
```

Comment: Does the table that is mapped to `Customer` contain any rows? If not, your application behaves just as expected. If it does contain rows, show us your mapping and the SQL that was executed by NHibernate.

Comment: Of course, my table contains rows! I added XML-file in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the xml mapping files to the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())`? You have to make the embedded resource. Otherwise you will have the behavoir you are describing.

Go to the properties of the files to change the build action.

Comment: Yes, of course, I changed build action for my XML-file on Embedded Resource. Can you explain me about `Have you added the xml mapping files to the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())?`.

Comment: The Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly is the executing assambly. It should contain the xml files. Normally you whould put your entities in an seperate assambly. Than you have to change the configuration.

Comment: It's just console application for studing, and my assemble contaions Customer.nbm.xml-file.

Comment: The filename should be Customer.hbm.xml

Answer (score 1):

The root tag of a mapping XML file has to be `hibernate-mapping` (note the "g" at the end).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed it, but my application doesn't work again :(

Comment: @Heidel As I already wrote in another comment, please show us the SQL that NHibernate executes.

Comment: Can you explain me how to get the SQL that NHibernate executes? I just started to study NHibernate.

Comment: @Heidel `cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x => { x.LogSqlInConsole = true; });`

Comment: I again got just string `"Enter any key to exit..."` in console and nothing more. What does it mean?

Comment: the profiler http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof is usually pretty helpful and also shows executed sql